# When the user inputs to repeat the code, I get an error

Tags: java, loops, indexing, repeat

I get this error when I try to repeat the code.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
Type a sentence and this program will tell you
how many vowels there are (excluding 'y'):
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1934)
        at countvowels.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Java Result: 1

Here is my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int answer = 0;
    System.out.println("Count Vowels \n============");

    // the do-while loop makes sure that the code is executed at least once
do {
        if(answer == 1) {
            System.out.println("You have chosen to count the vowels in another phrase");
        }

        System.out.println("Type a sentence and this program will tell you\nhow many vowels there       are (excluding 'y'):");
        String string1;

        string1 = input.nextLine();
        string1 = string1.toLowerCase();

        int vowels=0;
        int i = 0;

        for (String Vowels : string1.split(" ")) {
            for (i = 0; i < Vowels.length(); i++) {

                int letter = Vowels.charAt(i);
                if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i'
                        || letter == 'o' || letter == 'u') {
                    vowels++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Vowels.substring(0,1)
                    + Vowels.substring(1) + " has " + vowels + " vowels");
            vowels = 0;
        }

  System.out.println("Would you like to check another phrase in the Vowel Counter? if so Press 1           if not press 2");

} while(input.nextInt() == 1);


System.out.println("Have a nice day");
}

}
```

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, what is the runtime value of the string which results in the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are getting this exception, when you have a word that contains just a single character. To eliminate this, and to also enhance your code, I would replace this line:

```
System.out.println(Vowels.substring(0,1) + Vowels.substring(1) + " has " + vowels + " vowels");
```

with:

```
System.out.println(Vowels + " has " + vowels + " vowels");
```

Also, modify the loop ending with the following:

nextInt(), reads just the next integer value.. So the line breaker stays in the buffer, and is later processed by the nextLine() command.

Modify your loop ending with the following:

```
    answer = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
}
while (answer == 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! However when I press 1 as the user input, It doesn't ask them for the new phrase it goes straight into saying " has 0 vowels" would you like like to try again, sorta thing.

Comment: Check my modified answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your error come from your use of charAt()
This exception is thrown when the index is equal to the size of the string.

Comment: What do you suggest that I do to fix this?